# Integrating piecewise function having break points

Tags: integration

How to integrate $f (x) $ from $0$ to $2$ where $f (x) =0 $ when $x=n/(n+1)$ and $f (x) =1$ otherwise? (n is a natural number )

I tried breaking the integrals at points where $x=n/(n+1)$ but I'm not being able to write all the terms upto 2 using that. I'm a bit confused.Can you please illustrate the method to solve? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_0^2 f(x) \, dx & = \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx + \int_1^2 f(x) \, dx \\
& = \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} f(x) \, dx + \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{2}{3}} f(x) \, dx+ \int_{\frac{2}{3}}^{\frac{3}{4}} f(x) \, dx+ \dotsb + \int_1^2 f(x) \, dx \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{n+1}{n+2}-\frac{n}{n+1}\right] + \int_1^2 f(x) \, dx \\
& = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right] + \int_1^2 f(x) \, dx \\
& = 1 + 1\\
&=2.
\end{align*}

Note that $\frac{n}{n+1} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, therefore you need to break the integral into $[0,1]$ to $[1,2]$. The function is $1$ on $[1,2]$ so the last integral is $1$. Then break the integral on $[0,1]$ as shown above. On each of those intervals $f(x)=1$.

Comment: Yeah but how did you get the last term which integrates from 1 to 2? 1 is not even of the form n/(n+1)

Comment: @SanchayanDutta please read the added explanation.